# Blackberry map point click event

Tags: blackberry, dictionary

I am new to blackberry .  I am working on blackberry maps . I have to mark map points dynamically on map field .

The thing is  when user clicks on a map point a new screen should start .

Can i have a change listener to this map point and when user taps a new screen should pushed

Please help me

Comment: Which OS version are you developing for?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/documentation/ww_java_lbs/visualizing_a_location_1984872_11.html

Comment: @MisterSmith Can you tell me for os 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you manage to capture the click (you can do that by several means, one is overriding `navigationClick`), then you can translate the field coordinates to world coordinates using `MapField.convertFieldToWorld`. Then check if that matches any of your points.

Check the docs for [`MapField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html). Also have a look at the `EmbeddedMapDemo` included with the JDK.